# Ansible playbook variable/facts not available later on in playbook

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible playbook which first creates an instance on google cloud, then loads the new instance into a group. then it goes ahead and tries to run a role for the group which would update the new instance settings. I got most of the code from the [Ansible documentation on Google Cloud](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/guide_gce.html).

All I really have added is adding `vars_prompt` to get the instance name (as `t_customername`) and a var for number of seats for the software.

In my playbook, I use a `vars_prompt` to gather some user input. I use these vars in the playbook:

```
- name: Create Customer
hosts: localhost
gather_facts: no
connection: local

vars:
  machine_type: n1-standard-1 # default
  image: appname-cloud-base
  service_account_email: myemailaccount@developer.gserviceaccount.com
  credentials_file: /home/developer/ansible/appnamecloud.json
  project_id: appnamecloud

vars_prompt:
  - name: "t_customername"
    prompt: "enter customer name"
    private: no
  - name: "tag"
    prompt: "enter tag"
  private: no
- name: "t_seats"
  prompt: "enter number of simultaneous seats or -1 for unlimited."   
  private: no
```

tasks:
      ...

After initializing the new instances, I add it to a group with add_host, then I go ahead and start a new section where I want to call a role and have the variables `t_customname` and `t_seats` passed to the role. At first I thought the variables would automatically be in scope within the role but the role said they were undefined. Then I tried to assign them like so:

```
- name: Manage new instances
  hosts: my_instances
  connection: ssh
  sudo: True

  roles:
    - role: update      
  vars:
    dbinstalltype: "CREATE"
    customername: "{{ t_customername }}"
    seats: "{{ t_seats }}"
```

and Ansible would throw an error in the role when I tried to access `{{customername}}` saying that `{{t_customername}}` was undefined.

I tested further by just trying to do a debug line in the above section under `sudo: True` line and it shows that `t_customername` and `t_seats` are undefined there as well. I also tried calling set_fact in the 1st code section to see if that would help but those vars are also undefined in the second code section.

Is it because of the way that I am structuring my two -name sections? How can I pass my `vars_prompt` variables to the next section/roles?

Here is my [full file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8yWi32HupMTMHBKQjI2YzRNU0U).

Comment: After you check the answer, please take a moment to update the question with relevant information: `vars` you included above is not relevant, `add_host` is relevant. Please pay attention to indentation of your code in SO formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define variables in your `add_host` task, not in the subsequent play:

```
- name: Add host to groupname
  add_host:
    hostname: "{{ newstatic.address }}
    groupname: my_instances
    dbinstalltype: "CREATE"
    customername: "{{ t_customername }}"
    seats: "{{ t_seats }}"
  with_items: "{{ gce.instance_data }}"
```

---

Explanation:

Variables are subject to lazy evaluation in Ansible, so it is only the moment you use `customername` (somewhere inside `update` role) that Ansible looks at its content for the first time, finds a template `{{ t_customername }}` and tries to resolve it with the value of `t_customername` variable which is undefined.

With variables defined in `add_host` task, the evaluation takes place at the moment `add_host` is executed.

---

Regarding your title "*playbook variable/facts not available later on in playbook*":

- variables defined with `vars_prompt` are variables, not facts (i.e. they are not bound to any host - that's also why you won't be able to access these values with `hostvars` magic variable);
- as hinted by the indentation, these variables are available only in a play in which they were defined.